# Capistrano security best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, deployment, capistrano

The company I work for has been using capistrano for Rails apps deployment. we have app user(e.g. foo_app) created for each web apps, and they all belong to a webapp group with no password sudo privilege:

```
%webapp ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

in our cap deploy.rb we set a ssh key pair to allow capistrano to ssh to the server as the app user and do all cap tasks.

```
set :ssh_options, {:username=>'foo_app', :keys => File.join(ENV['HOME'],'.ssh', 'id_rsa_deploy')}
```

It works well but **I feel a bit uncomfortable to have a nopasswd sudoer run my app's processes, if the app process gets compromised, the attacker could easily take over entire server.**

My question is, is there any way to have a different user that runs my app, preferably without sudo permission? Ideally I want to have a single 'deploy' user to do all capistrano remote tasks:

```
set :ssh_options, {:username=>'deploy', :keys => File.join(ENV['HOME'],'.ssh', 'id_rsa_deploy')}
```

but I want to have capistrano use a app specific user to run my processes like unicorn, delayed jobs etc.

I have played with **:admin_runner, :runner** variables but they don't work as I expected.  I could change some 3rd party recipes to sudo as foo_app when starting processes like unicorn, delayed jobs etc. but that's a lot of work to keep them updated.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you may want to consider restricting that nopasswd rule a bit. I'm not sure the specifics of your deploy, but I generally create a user dedicated to deploying, and give him nopasswd rules *only* for the commands I need to escalate during the deploy - this usually winds up being service restart commands only, possibly specific chown commands as well. If you need more interactive help, hop on `#capistrano` during US Pacific daytime and I am happy to try to help you out - I just missed you this weekend.

Example of a restricted nopasswd rule, in case you need a reference:

```
webapp ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/sv restart myservice
```

Resulting ruleset:

```
webapp@host:~$ sudo -ll
User torrancew may run the following commands on this host:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sv restart myservice
```

-torrancew